# Redshift - Sorting data by week

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, amazon-redshift

I am trying to sort some data in Redshift by week.

```
select CONCAT(CONCAT('Week', ' '), 
EXTRACT(WEEK FROM sale_date::date + '1 day'::interval)) as date,count(*) as total 
from sales 
where sale_date between ('2019-03-22' - 30) and '2019-03-22' 
group by EXTRACT(WEEK FROM  sale_date::date + '1 day'::interval)
order by 1 asc;
```

The above query works fine however the output is as below:

```
Week 10, 10
Week 11, 20
Week 12, 3
Week 7, 12
Week 8, 3
Week 9, 5
```

How could I modify the above query such that the output is as below:

```
Week 7, 12
Week 8, 3
Week 9, 5
Week 10, 10
Week 11, 20
Week 12, 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*you need to cat your extracted week value to a `numeric type` for `order by` statement. So convert*

`order by 1 asc` **to**

`order by cast(EXTRACT(WEEK FROM sale_date::date + '1 day'::interval) as integer)`